# Подскажите регулярное выражение в Notepad++, чтобы удалить скобки с содержимым

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть текст:

```
текст текст (??????? ????)  текст 
текст (???????) есть тектс
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, регулярное выражение, чтобы удалить скобки с его содержимым (вопросы).

Comment: Можно так `\(.*?\)`